# How to measure processing time and bottlenecks on callbacks?

Tags: performance, callback, plotly, pattern-matching, plotly-dash

I'm working on a web app that has an advanced accordion style with some effects that I'm using pattern match callbacks on the engine to create the effects you can see on the gif below:
[image]

The problem starts when I try to add more categories and subcategories... So it starts to work very slow;

I'm trying to use 7 different categories with 30+- subcategories in each category.

I thought the problem was about the loops to create the style and other information but after exploring the callback graph I did note that maybe other parts are being affected by this collapsed part;

I have isolated the component and created an application to test it:
[image]

As we can see, it takes some time to run the component, but on the callback graph it says that it was very fast;

So, I would like to know what's the best way to understand what's happening on my callbacks to detect where is my bottleneck; I suspect that it's not directly on the loops and so on, but it's happening because it takes some time until rendering the modifications to the user.

Any help or reference would be very welcome.

If you need any other clarification please let me know.

Regards,

Comment: 7 x 30 subcategories does not seem a sufficient reason to slow down the widget. Aren't you performing heavy processing in the callbacks ? 

Code profiling is your best friend.

Comment: Hey Yves, thanks for your answer; Yes I do agree with you, I did assume that the problem was on my side, but after debugging all the callbacks, measuring the time of each computation, isolating the accordion component, and investigating the callback graph... I did note that the problem really wasn't on my code but in some Dash internal stuff that I don't know =/ Maybe it's related to the dash renderer or something like this;  
I would prefer that the error was on my side.